# Problem with Process.Start() method

Tags: c#-2.0, process, mutex, child-process

I have a child.exe which takes command line arguments. I need to start that child.exe from another parent.exe application and need to pass different command line arguments to that child.exe.
I tried with the following code.

```
Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"R:\bin\child.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "CONSUMER";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();

process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"R:\bin\child.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "SUPERVISOR";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
```

But the problem here is each time when I call process.Start(), a separate exe is created. I need only one instance of child.exe running which would accept different command line arguments.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's going to create a new process, if you want to pass an existing process new arguments you're best of with some kind of IPC.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your child application could be set up to use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to ensure it is only run once.

Secondly, you probably want to look into the [Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.aspx) functionality to allow you to communicate across your different processes to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or dynamically load the assembly into the parent.exe process and call a method in it. You can even do it in an isolated AppDomain, which (if child.exe is written in managed code) will likely be the solution you really want. Take a look at this MSDN article for starters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0z09xw.aspx

Answer (score -4):

in code create a bat file whish will contain your parameters. the parent exe will call the bat file. after the parent end delete the bat file.